# Two ZFS Array's In a single Pool need to separate them

Tags: zfs

I'm not sure if anyone can help me on this but i'll give it a go.

Currently using Ubuntu ZFS to provide me with a ZFS array, which is made up of two RaidZ1 arrays, 3x3TB and 3x2TB discs.

However stupidly when installing the larger array, I added the second array to the same pool, which already had a large amount of data in (currently called storage). My plan was to use the 3x2TB discs as backup discs, incase something went wrong with the fileserver or the ZFS setup itself.

So I really have two questions one is there anyway to move all data to the larger array, when it's in the same zfs pool? (current name is storage for pool name). Then is there a way to shutdown the remaining old unused 3x2TB array, so that the pool can be shrunk?

So I'm stuck with a problem and I'm not really sure how to proceed and don't even know if what I am looking for is even possible so any clues would be great.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your pool cannot be shrunk. Once you have added devices to your pool, you cannot remove them but only replace them by same size or larger devices.

What you can do assuming you have enough storage elsewhere is to send your whole datasets to another device, destroy/rebuild your pool the way you originally wanted to and finally receive back your data.

Comment: Yea was hoping I wasn't having to waste money just to get the right size pool, as usual something hasn't been implemented because you shouldn't have to do if you are in a perfect setup, which is stupid considering there are multiple reason why you might want to shrink a pool ah the wisdom of some Dev's thinking its not possible to make a mistake. 

Seems even more crazy when you can actually see how much each drive is using by using Iostat and yet you can't move data to a certain array even though the process who be easy if a long process.

Comment: I believe this wasn't implemented not "because you shouldn't have to do so" but because it is overly complex/risky to implement compared to the benefit. Excerpt from http://eworldproblems.mbaynton.com/2014/01/zfs-block-pointer-rewrite-status-2013/  *The short summary sounds like achieving this via “block pointer rewrite” will almost surely never happen, because any code that correctly updates all necessary data structures would, in Matt’s opinion, introduce code that is too confusing/ugly/unmaintainable to encourage further ZFS development of other kinds.*